# Find distribution of Y = WX where X is normal and W is discrete

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

**Problem**

$X \sim N(0, 1)$

Let $W$ be independent of $X$ with $P(W = 1) = P(W = −1) = \frac{1}{2}$

$$Y = W X$$

What is the distribution of $Y$?

**Work**

$P(Y=y) = P(WX = y) = P(X=\frac{y}{W}) \\
= P(X=y)P(W=1) + P(X=-y)P(W=-1) = \frac{1}{2}f_X(y) + \frac{1}{2}f_X(-y) \\
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}(e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} + e^{\frac{x^2}{2}})$

I'm not sure how to determine the distribution of Y from the PDF I found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Y > y)
= \mathbb{P}(Y > y | W =+1)\mathbb{P}(W =+1) + \mathbb{P}(Y > y | W =-1)\mathbb{P}(W =-1)
= \frac{1}{2}\left[\mathbb{P}(X > y ) + \mathbb{P}(X < -y )\right]
= \mathbb{P}(X > y )\quad  \because \mathbb{P}(X > y ) = \mathbb{P}(X < -y ) \textrm{ due to symmetry of } N(0,1) \textrm{ about 0}
\end{align}
So $Y \sim X$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{2}\left[\mathbb{P}(X > y ) + \mathbb{P}(X > -y )\right]$ where $\mathbb{P}(X > -y )$?

Comment: No, because $\{WX >y|W=-1\} = \{-X >y\} = \{X < -y\} $.